# Number of students in the school

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An School has $1200$ students. Each pupil takes $5$ classes a day. Each teacher teaches $4$ classes. Each class has $30$ students and $1$ teacher. How many teachers are there at School?

$\text{(A)}\ 30 \qquad \text{(B)}\ 32 \qquad \text{(C)}\ 40 \qquad \text{(D)}\ 45 \qquad \text{(E)}\ 50$

Although this question seems very easy at first glance, It confused me a lot. my guess is $\frac{1200}{30}=40$. but it doesn't make sense because I didn't use many information in the problem. can you please explain how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $5 \times 1200$ "student-class" combinations, meaning that if you add up the # of students in all of the classes combined, you get $6000$.  At 30 students a class $\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of classes each day. Then the number of teachers is simply $\frac{n}{4}$ (since each teacher teaches four classes each day). There are a total $\frac{1200}{30} \times 5 = 200$ classes each day. Therefore the number of teachers is $\frac{200}{4} = 50.$ I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will take a different approach and use dimensional analysis to solve the problem.

Define the units of $[C]$ as classes , $[S]$ as students, $[T]$ as teachers and $[h]$ as hours.

We have $1200 [S]$, $30 [S]/[C]$, $1 [T]/[C]$ $5 [h]$ for each student and $4 [h] $ for each teacher.

Notice that $$\frac{[S]}{\frac{[S]/[C]}{[h]}}=[c][h]$$
and $$\frac{[T]}{\frac{[T]/[C]}{[h]}}=[c][h]$$

This gives us a relationship between all the units i.e.
$$\frac{[S]}{\frac{[S]/[C]}{[h]}}=\frac{[T]}{\frac{[T]/[C]}{[h]}}=[c][h]$$

This, together with the values we have, gives us $$\frac{1200 \cdot 5 }{30}=4 \cdot x$$ where $x$ is the number of teachers, solving for $x$ we get $$x=50$$.